# Very basic question about integrals and substitution

Tags: integration

I am a bit frustrated since I have done that a few years ago but know I suddenly forgot and it's such a "strange" question that I don't even have the keywords to search for it. My questions is: how exactly do we treat the argument of a function like $f(x-x_0)$ when it comes to the $dx$ in the integral, when we perform integration on such a thing?

My questions is related to this proof:

> **Proof:** Let $t'=t±t_0$, i.e., $t=t'\mp t_o$, we have
>
> $$\begin{align*}
> \mathcal{F}[x(t±t_0)]\quad &: \quad \int^\infty_{-\infty}x(t±{t_0})e^{-j \omega t}dt'=\int^\infty_{-\infty}x(t')e^{-j \omega(t'\mp t_0)}dt\\
> &:e^{±j\omega t_0}\int^\infty_{-\infty}x(t')e^{-j\omega t'}dt'=X(j \omega)e^{±j \omega t_0}
> \end{align*}$$

''Naively'' one would consider that since we write the first integral (the integral of $x(t \pm t_0)$, one could be tempted to write $d(t \pm t_0)$ instead of the $dt$ for the infinitesimal in the integral. However, I am not sure if that even as a meaning and therefore why should that not be done/what is the justification?

Source: http://fourier.eng.hmc.edu/e101/lectures/handout3/node2.html

P.S.
Maybe, following this idea, one could develop $d(t \pm t_0)$ into $dt \pm dt_0$ and consider that since $t$ is the variable and $t_0$ is a constant... that $dt_0 =0$, but I don't know if that makes any sense at all.

Comment: $t_0$ is a constant so $d(t \pm t_0)=dt$.

Comment: Thanks for answering very fast ! yes I know that $t_0$ is a constant. So is it correct to develop $d(t\pm t_0)$ as $dt \pm dt_0$ into $dt+0= dt$ just because $t_0$ is a constant?

Comment: yes, the  integral limits are infinity and -infinity.

Comment: Sorry, what is the relation with the bounds of the integral and my question about the dt ?

Comment: Yes it's correct and imho exactly how you should think of that (I was commenting on your first comment)

Comment: when you change variables, you should adjust the integral limits. In your case, they don't change.

Comment: @ReiHenigman Are you are refering of how I derive the $d(t\pm t_0)$ by distributing the $d$ on $t$ and $t_0$? That you think is exaclty the right way?

Comment: Maybe it will be clearer if you remember that, by definition, the *differential* of a function $f$ is $\;\mathrm d f=f'(x)\,\mathrm dx$.

Comment: @Machupicchu yes. Also see Bernard's comment :)

Comment: fantastic answers thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basis of substitution is that $d(\phi(x))=\phi'(x) dx$, which gives $$\int  f(\phi(x))\phi'(x) dx =\int f(\phi(x))d(\phi(x))$$

Supposing that $\phi(x)=x+\alpha$, we have $d(\phi(x))=dx$, that is: $$\int_\Bbb R f(x+\alpha) dx =\int_\Bbb R f(x+\alpha) d(x+\alpha)$$
Naturally, you must account for limits of integration, but since yours are infinite, they will stay the same.

Essentially what you are doing is translating the function by $\pm t_0$. Integrating across the whole real space will still give the same answer at the end.

Comment: Fantastic and very clear answer! Just one question: is that sort of included/implied in the fundamental thm of integration or does this have a particular name ?

Comment: This is known as [integration by substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_substitution).

Comment: oh yes of course! The worse is that I used that maybe 1.5 years ago or so but I forget ... Hopefully will remember forever this time

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this is your point, but see: put $t'=t+t_0$, then $dt'/dt=1$.

That is: $t=t'-t_0$ and $dt'=dt$.
Hence
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty x(t+t_0)e^{-j\omega t}dt=\int_{-\infty}^\infty x(t')e^{-j\omega (t'-t_0)}dt'$$